# How to order by one-to-many association date with a decent performance?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the above models in my MySQL database:

```
Blogs (id: integer, name: varchar)
Posts (id: integer, name: varchar, blog_id: integer, created_at: date)
```

I want to retrieve a list of all the blogs, ordered by the ones that have the newests posts.

I've reached that with the following query:

```
SELECT b.*, (SELECT p.created_at FROM posts p WHERE p.blog_id = b.id ORDER BY p.created_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_post_created_at FROM blogs b ORDER BY last_post_created_at DESC;
```

But this query is too slow and I'm unable to use it on my application.

Do you guys have a good solution for that?

Thank you.

Comment: How many rows does the `Blogs` table have?

Comment: Add a `(blog_id, created_at)` index at the `Posts` table for this query.

Comment: @ypercube Around 10k and posts around 100k

Comment: And do you really need all those 10K rows returned?

Comment: @ypercube, no I don't. But even limit 5 the query is super slow.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15035/discussion-between-ypercube-and-robertokl)

Comment: Yes, because it has to find the whole 10K values for the `last_post_created_at` and then do a filesort to get the most recent 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A rewriting of the query:

```
SELECT b.*, 
       p.last_post_created_at 
FROM blogs b 
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT blog_id,
             MAX(created_at) AS last_post_created_at
      FROM posts  
      GROUP BY blog_id 
    ) AS p
    ON  p.blog_id = b.id  
ORDER BY last_post_created_at DESC;
```

An index on `(blog_id, created_at)` will help both this and your version.

If you want to limit the number of blogs returned, you should add the `ORDER BY` in the subquery and put the `LIMIT` there:

```
SELECT b.*, 
       p.last_post_created_at 
FROM blogs b 
  LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT blog_id,
             MAX(created_at) AS last_post_created_at
      FROM posts  
      GROUP BY blog_id 
      ORDER BY last_post_created_at DESC
        LIMIT 100
    ) AS p
    ON  p.blog_id = b.id  
ORDER BY last_post_created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html). Great thing to know and use!

Comment: Does the view helps with the performance issue? If I do the same query, it will take the same time as the query, dosen't it?

Comment: On the contrary - a view prepares the data for your query live. It is a virtual table based on a query definition.